# requesting associated objects and put them in an instance variable?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations

With these associations;

- Product belongs_to :thing
- Thing has_many :products

Having selected multiple objects like this:

```
@products = Product.find(1,2,3)
```

How would i go about requesting their corresponding associated objects in an another instance variable? as such:

```
@things = (the things of product 1,2 and 3)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@things = @products.collect(&:thing)
```

Comment: only problem with this is that:

 when product1 belongs to thing1 
and product2 belongs ALSO to thing1

i get two times thing1 while i wanted only one

Comment: You can call `.uniq` on the array to dedupe it... `@things = @products.collect(&:thing).uniq`